# Pasar dos listas a json

Tags: python, json

Me estoy iniciando en python y encontré este ejercicio, el cual quería resolver pero no he podido haber si me echan una mano. necesito pasar estas dos listas a un json

```py
lista_1 = ["Una","frase","formada","con","palabras"]
lista_2 = ["Otra","frase","con","otras","palabras"]
```

output >> `[{"Una":"Otra"},{"frase":"frase"}..........]`

Saludos

Comment: `dict(zip(lista_1,lista_2))`

Comment: @Christian eso que propones devuelve `{"una":"otra", "frase":"frase", ...}`, que es un diccionario. El output es una lista de diccionarios.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora? Aquí no hacemos tareas. Demuestranos que eres parte del esfuerzo de hayar la respuesta a tu propia pregunta! Si tienes código hecho agregalo a la pregunta a pesar de que este no haga lo que pides.

Comment: @DanteS. es verdad, no había visto bien el output esperado :/

Comment: `[{k:v} for k,v in zip(lista_1, lista_2)]`

Comment: @DanteS. ahora sip :D

Comment: @christian Bien hecho :D pero no estoy muy de acuerdo con darle la respuesta.

Comment: @DanteS. sin una buena explicación poco le servirá, tal vez luego busque la doc de `zip()` y luego pase a buscar que es esa sintaxis `[..]`, así que tal vez esté fomentando que el OP busque información, sé que no es lo adecuado pero todos quieren salir de un apuro